# Archlinux: External display monitor hijacking laptop monitor

Tags: arch-linux

I have a question regarding how to check if display drivers are loading correctly at boot. I am running Archlinux on a laptop, and seemingly cannot proceed past the boot selector screen without a specific external monitor attached. I would like to use the laptop monitor, however, after booting through GRUB and a few lines of script, output to the laptop monitor ceases.

I have tried to boot with multiple external monitors attached, and only the external monitor that I initially attached to the laptop displays video output after boot ( i.e. if I attach the laptop to the specific external monitor, I can get the system to boot to a log in screen ). Display output to the laptop monitor worked before the first time this external monitor was attached to the system. I have entered BIOS, and set the default monitor as internal, however, the problem persists. I do not automatically boot into a graphical environment ( I don't have the XServer automatically running after booting ).

I am wondering if this could be an issue with the loading of the display driver? Does ArchLinux store any persistent settings for the display output, or could this possibly be a firmware issue? Is there a way through GRUB to revert to the laptop’s monitor? Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time,

Nils